# DBeaver SQL Error [1406] [22001].. Data truncation: Data too long Issues and Questions

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I'm in the process of moving a MySQL v5.5 DB to MySQL v8, using DBeaver. Table 'creds' is defined in v5 as varchar(200), latin1_swedish_ci and at the moment the same in v8. Doing an 'Import Data' I set it up to transfer the table from v5 to v8 and I'm using the default settings for the process. When its run I get this error;

"SQL Error [1406] [22001]: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'creds' at row 4"

The longest value for 'creds' in the entire table is 68 bytes so why am I getting this error? As you can see from the error it says "at row 4" trust me it's not row 4, so what does that mean exactly?
I can't find an exact example of this issue anywhere so I'm hoping smarter people can help.

UPDATE

'creds' is actually a column in the table called 'NetLog', in a DB called 'ncm'.

The Type

```
varChar(200), Collation = latin1_swedish_ci, null = YES
```

```
CREATE TABLE `NetLog-2023-05-29` (
 `row_number` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `recordID` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `netID` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `subNetOfID` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
 `timeout` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `ID` int(6) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '000000',
 `callsign` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `Fname` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `grid` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
 `traffic` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT '',
 `tactical` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
 `logdate` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Check-in Date & Time',
 `activity` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
 `latitude` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
 `longitude` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
 `Lname` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
 `netcontrol` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
 `active` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
 `frequency` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
 `comments` varchar(3000) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `creds` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
 `timeonduty` int(8) DEFAULT '0',
 `netcall` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Mode` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `logclosedtime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `county` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `state` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `district` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `firstLogIn` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `tt` int(2) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
 `pb` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `phone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `dttm` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'When row was created',
 `ipaddress` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `band` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `w3w` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `home` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `cat` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Custom',
 `section` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Section',
 `testnet` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `team` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `aprs_call` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `country` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `facility` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'example: Hospital Name',
 `onSite` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Is the station on site? Yes, No',
 `delta` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Indicates a change in location',
 `city` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'City of callsign',
 PRIMARY KEY (`recordID`),
 KEY `callsign` (`callsign`),
 KEY `netID` (`netID`,`callsign`),
 KEY `id_netID` (`netID`,`ID`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `callsign_index` (`callsign`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=133749 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='Amateur Radio Net Check-in Log'
```

Comment: Why should I provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example for any SQL query question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: We basically need to see the new table create and also specifically its Charset rather than the collation, although this comment should give you a bit of a clue

Comment: I do not know how or even if I can see the SQL behind the transfer of data within the DBeaver application.  I was just hoping someone else who actually knows DBeaver could tell me why a 68 byte piece of data won't fit into a varchar(200).

Comment: Please do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE creds` and look at the output or just show us the value on `CHARSET=` For the new database that is of course

Comment: @RiggsFolly Now you have caught me in an error.  'creds' is actually a column in the table called 'NetLog', in a DB called 'ncm'. My bad.! The Type = varChar(200), Collation = latin1_swedish_ci, null = YES, and there are no defaults. Charset = armscii8, ascii, big5, binary, cp1250, cp1251, cp1256, cp1257, cp850, cp852, cp866, cp932, dec8, eucjpms, euchre, gb2312, gbk, geostd8, greek, Hebrew, hp8, keybcs2, koi8r, koi8u, latin1,2,5,7, mace, macron, axis, swe7, tis620, ucs2, uzis, utf16, utf8, and utf8mb4. I hope that's the correct stuff.

Comment: It is so much easier to read if you put things in the question rather than a comment

Comment: Also, ___if you do as I asked above and show the output from___ a `SHOW CREATE TABLE NetLog` we dont have to guess which one of the complete set of charsets you actually used!

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Never knew I should put more things in the original question, thanks for the hint. I've never run a SHOW CREATE TABLE before so was unaware of it. But I've now added it to the question as requested.

Comment: This sounds like another DBeaver issue. Why not do a simple EXPORT from the old DB and IMPORT into the new DB

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried the EXPORT from the prod to the new table. This was the result; Error occurred during batch insert
(you can disable batch insert in order to skip particular rows).

Reason:
SQL Error [1406] [22001]: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'creds' at row 4

Comment: Do you have access to phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench or even simpler the command line using terminal?